# Angular 9 - multiple routes are getting activated

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to log-in a user and redirect the user to dashboard.

The whole process works fine, but in the interim i'm seeing the login form component AND the dashboard component at the same time (they're 2 different routes).

What am I doing wrong? Why would angular show both components at the same time? Is it because of the delay in HTTP call that the canActivate is slow to go false for one guard? What can be done?

I have 2 guards (one will redirect to "/" if authenticated, the other will redirect to "/login" if not authenticated):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UnauthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {

  }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

    return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
      .pipe(
        map(x => {
          if (x) {
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        })
      )

  }

}
```

and

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {

  }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

    return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
      .pipe(
        map(x => {

          if (!x) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
          }

          return true;
        })
      );

  }

}
```

and a bunch of routes in 2 different modules:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { UnauthenticatedGuard } from './guard/unauthenticated.guard';


const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [UnauthenticatedGuard]
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule { }
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './pages/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AuthenticatedGuard } from '../auth/guard/authenticated.guard';

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticatedGuard]
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out. In the interim logic where i was redirecting after authentication to "/", i had to wrap it around

```
this.zone.run(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      })
```